# Using setTo in OpenCV with CV_32F images

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

I have two CV_32F images V1 and V2, of same size 512x512

I am trying to do:

```
float epsilon = 0.05f;
cv::Mat V = cv::abs(V1-V2);
cv::Mat mask = V < epsilon;
V1.setTo(V2, mask);
```

I checked that mask is a 512x512 CV_8U image.

setTo triggers a "checkScalar" assertion fail.

When I read the documentation of setTo, it says:

> mask
> Operation mask of the same size as *this. Its non-zero elements
> indicate which matrix elements need to be copied. The mask has to be
> of type CV_8U and can have 1 or multiple channels

Is the documentation wrong? Does mask have to be another type than CV_8U when masking a CV_32F image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTo()` is only for spreading a *scalar* across the Mat subject.

For array data, you want `copyTo()`. Note that this *pushes* data *into* the *argument* Mat, doesn't *pull* it into the subject Mat. The `m` argument receives those values. Flip subject and argument, relative to your previous `setTo()` attempt.

The docs specify input arguments to be a generic `InputArray` very often but the actual type is restricted at runtime (`checkScalar` and such). The docs for `setTo()` say that it's expecting a scalar `value()`, which means no array types.

---

I don't know why you'd question the `mask` argument or the Mat element type. That's all fine.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was confused by setTo and copyTo. Mask type was fine

Comment: I'm surprised though, why is this scalar constraint not enforced at compile time via the setTo function template? Should it work with a 1x1 Matrix?